# Cmake not able to find CGAL library(installed using vcpkg)

Tags: c++, cmake, cgal, vcpkg

This is the error message:

```
CMake Error at D:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:788 (_find_package):
  By not providing "FindCGAL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "CGAL", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "CGAL" with any of
  the following names:

    CGALConfig.cmake
    cgal-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "CGAL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "CGAL_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "CGAL"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package)
```

I am trying to use the *vcpkg toolchain file* when building the project in Cmake; so all my installed libraries are available for Cmake but it is not working.

Comment: Please add the cmake command to your question.

Comment: also add a minimal example of the CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Hi, I am really new to compilation so I am using the Cmake GUI. So the cmake command I am using its just launching the UI. The cmake that I am using it's the one vcpkg generated when installed. When I installed vcpkg this came up: CMake projects should use: "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"